# Is it a good way to implement Font enum like this?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I have two ways of implementation, and I can not figure out which one is better, or maybe exist other, better way. Please give me advice.

If anyone is interested:

with

```
let date1 = NSDate()
Fonts1.Avenir.AvenirNext.Heavy(15)
print(-date1.timeIntervalSinceNow * 1000)
let date2 = NSDate()
Fonts.AvenirNext(.Heavy).getFont(15)
print(-date2.timeIntervalSinceNow * 1000)
```

i got result:

```
7.06201791763306
0.348985195159912
```

### Fonts.HelveticaNeue.Bold(15)

```
enum Fonts {
    enum Default: HelveticaNeueFontProtocol {
        static var familyName: String { return "HelveticaNeue" }
    }
    enum Copperplate: CopperplateFontProtocol {}
    enum HelveticaNeue: HelveticaNeueFontProtocol {}
}

// MARK: - FontProtocol
protocol FontProtocol {}
private extension FontProtocol {
    static var familyName: String { return "\(self)" }
    static func getFont(style: String, size: CGFloat) -> UIFont { return UIFont(name: familyName + "-" + style, size: size) ?? UIFont(name: familyName, size: size) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(size) }
}

// MARK: - Font Family Protocols
protocol CopperplateFontProtocol: NormalStyleFontProtocol {}
protocol HelveticaNeueFontProtocol: NormalStyleFontProtocol, BoldStyleFontProtocol {}

// MARK: - Font Style Protocols
protocol NormalStyleFontProtocol: FontProtocol {}
extension NormalStyleFontProtocol {
    private static var normal: String { return "" }
    static var Normal: (CGFloat) -> UIFont { return { getFont(normal, size: $0) } }
}
extension NormalStyleFontProtocol where Self: RegularStyleFontProtocol {
    private static var normal: String { return regular }
}

protocol RegularStyleFontProtocol: FontProtocol {}
extension RegularStyleFontProtocol {
    private static var regular: String { return "Regular" }
    static var Regular: (CGFloat) -> UIFont { return { getFont(regular, size: $0) } }
}

protocol BoldStyleFontProtocol: FontProtocol {}
extension BoldStyleFontProtocol {
    private static var bold: String { return "Bold" }
    static var Bold: (CGFloat) -> UIFont { return { getFont(bold, size: $0) } }
}
```

### Fonts.HelveticaNeue(.Normal).getFont(15)

```
enum FontsStyle: String {
    case Normal = ""
    case Regular = "Regular"
    case Bold = "Bold"
    case BoldItalic = "BoldItalic"
}

enum Fonts {
    /// HelveticaNeue
    case Default(FontsStyle)
    /// .Normal | .Bold | .BoldItalic | .CondensedBlack | .CondensedBold | .Italic | .Light | .LightItalic | .Medium | .MediumItalic | .UltraLight | .UltraLightItalic | .Thin | .ThinItalic
    case HelveticaNeue(FontsStyle)

    private var default_: Fonts {
        return HelveticaNeue(.Normal)
    }

    var name: String {
        switch self {
            case .Default:
                return default_.name
            case .HelveticaNeue:
                return "HelveticaNeue"
        }
    }

    var style: FontsStyle {
        switch self {
            case .Default(let style):
                return style
            case .HelveticaNeue(let style):
                return style
        }
    }

    func getFont(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        let name = self.name
        let style = self.style.rawValue
        let font = UIFont(name: name + "-" + style, size: size) ?? UIFont(name: name, size: size) ?? UIFont.systemFontOfSize(size)
        return font
    }
}
```

Comment: pros of the first variant:
you know which styles are available, just by press ".".

Comment: cons of the first variant: you can't use it like func _(font: Fonts), only func _(font: UIFont)

Comment: Here's a nice article - https://medium.com/@topLayoutGuide/swift-custom-fonts-slightly-less-awful-f235e20027f3

Answer (score 0):

**You can use enum like this**

```
extension UIFont {
    enum Poppins {
        case regular(size: CGFloat)
        case medium(size: CGFloat)
        case semiBold(size: CGFloat)
        case bold(size: CGFloat)
        
        var font: UIFont! {
            switch self {
            case .regular(let size):
                return UIFont(name: "Poppins-Regular", size: size)
            case .medium(let size):
                return UIFont(name: "Poppins-Medium", size: size)
            case .semiBold(let size):
                return UIFont(name: "Poppins-SemiBold", size: size)
            case .bold(let size):
                return UIFont(name: "Poppins-Bold", size: size)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Use:**

```
let regular : UIFont = .Poppins.regular(size: 16).font
let medium : UIFont = .Poppins.medium(size: 16).font
let semiBold : UIFont = .Poppins.semiBold(size: 16).font
let bold : UIFont = .Poppins.bold(size: 16).font
```